# Checking types in a generic method

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

I to know if it is possible to have an if statement in a method that will check the type of the generic used. In the case that got me thinking about this I want to handle a pretty basic `Point2D` class and a `Point3D` class differently. In the case of the 3D point I need to access `Point3d.z`, and I am not sure whether or not this will cause problems A pseudo code version of what I would like to do is

```
public <T> void processPoints(T point) {
    process(point.x);
    process(point.y);
    if (T == Point3D) { // What do I do here?
        process(point.z); // Will accessing z cause problems?
    }
}
```

In reality the code `process` represents is a lot more complicated and `z` is dependent on `x` and `y` so I am looking for a way to avoid code duplication. I will probably figure out a way to overload the function instead, but I am curious so I can learn more about generics.

Comment: (That's the canonical example of not as "is-a" relationship. A 3D point is not a kind of 2D point.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I to know if it is possible to have an if statement in a method that will check the type of the generic used.

Not in general, no - because of *type erasure*. Basically the type of `T` isn't known at execution time.

You could use:

```
if (point instanceof Point3D)
```

but that's not *quite* the same as checking whether `T` itself is `Point3D`. It's probably a better idea though:

```
public void processPoints(Point point) {
    process(point.x);
    process(point.y);
    if (point instanceof Point3D) {
        Point3D point3d = (Point3D) point;
        process(point3d.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about plain old overloading and avoid generics?

```
public void processPoints(final Point2D point)
{
    process(point.x);
    process(point.y);
}

public void processPoints(final Point3D point)
{
    process(point.x);
    process(point.y);
    process(point.z);
}
```

If you only have instances of `Point2D` and `Point3D` why would you use a generic parameter `T`?

You should look for other ways to remove code duplication instead of using `instanceof` or the like.

Comment: This is how I ended up coding it up, but I was really just curious about how generics work.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) in runtime. JVM knows (almost) nothing about generics, they are mainly meant for compiler to check types. After checking types using generics compiler *replaces* all generic types, say `List<String>` becomes `List<Object>` after compilation, so it's not detectable at runtime.